# Local edits to a Github repository

Tags: git, github

I might get downvoted for the following question, but i'm really new to using Github and i have some doubts.

I'm working on a project, and since someone else wants to help me working on this, i created a private repository on github, where only i and the other person are allowed to see and edit the repo.

What it's not really clear is: i am working on my project locally and when i make some important changes, i will update the repository. But what happens when the other contributor will make some edits to the repository? Will i have, each time, to download a new edited version of the repository and work on that one until there is a new update, or is there any way to "download" only the edits to my repository and have them locally on the project i've always worked on?

Comment: It's Git 101. You will need to setup some flow. Simplest is before pushing do something like `git pull --rebase origin master` (assuming your remote is *origin* and the branch is *master*). You possible will get conflicts you have to resolve. This has to be iterated (in case that person is quick enough to push more changes) till you get a result. Never push with `--force` until you get the idea behind so called *published* (don't mess with *public*) repositories.

Comment: But what happens if, for example, i am at a certain point on my local project, while the repository is behind and i do this? Am i going to lose my progress and my local project will be "retro" updated to where the github repository is?

Comment: Please, read documentation. Take your time.